# Iterate over dates in a Pandas Dataframe to get the count of a different column per week

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, size, resampling

I am a java developer finding it a bit tricky to switch to python and Pandas. Im trying to iterate over dates of a Pandas Dataframe which looks like below,

```
    sender_user_id    created
0   1                 2016-12-19 07:36:07.816676
1   33                2016-12-19 07:56:07.816676
2   1                 2016-12-19 08:14:07.816676
3   15                2016-12-19 08:34:07.816676
```

what I am trying to get is a dataframe which gives me a count of the total number of transactions that have occurred per week. From the forums I have been able to get syntax for 'for loops' which iterate over indexes only. Basically I need a result dataframe which looks like this. The value field contains the count of sender_user_id and the date needs to be modified to show the starting date per week.

```
    date          value
0   2016-12-09    20
1   2016-12-16    36
2   2016-12-23    56
3   2016-12-30    32
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `week` and aggregate `size`:

```
#cast to datetime if necessary
df.created = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
print (df.resample('W', on='created').size().reset_index(name='value'))
     created  value
0 2016-12-25      4
```

If need another [offsets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases):

```
df.created = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
print (df.resample('W-FRI', on='created').size().reset_index(name='value'))
     created  value
0 2016-12-23      4
```

If need number of unique values per week aggregate by [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
df.created = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
print (df.resample('W-FRI', on='created')['sender_user_id'].nunique()
         .reset_index(name='value'))
     created  value
0 2016-12-23      3
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but im getting a weird error with resample.

Comment: TypeError: resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on'

Comment: You can use `df=df.set_index('created')` and then `print (df.resample('W').size().reset_index(name='value'))` becasue argument `on` works if have [pandas 0.19.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#other-enhancements) - check your version with `print (pd.show_versions())`

Comment: hi jezrael, u were right it was a version problem. I upgraded my pandas to get the right version... thanks a bunch